# How can I edit my code so that the output is the very next number greater than 3?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
for i in range(8):
  while i >3:
    print(i,end=" ")
    break
  # prints 4 5 6 7
```

I want to find out the very next I that is greater than 3.
 How can I edit my code so that the output is 4?

Comment: Why not just use `+1`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `if` statement instead:

```
for i in range(8):
    if i > 3:
        print(i)
        break
```

In your code, the break statement terminates only the `while` loop and so the `for` loop continues. If you use an `if` statement, the break will end the `for` loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but why  does the break end the for loop if I use an if statement?

Comment: Because `break` terminates the inner-most loop. So here, the only loop running is the for loop so that one ends. In your example, the inner-most for loop is the while loop so only that one ends. _(There are ways to break out of multiple loops at the same time however.)_

Answer (score 0):

you can try another module `itertools.dropwhile`:

```
>>> list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x:x<=3, range(8)))
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```